# Disabled firewall on a Asus router and now can't connect

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I have an ASUS RT-N12 wireless router with WAN web access. A dummy of the router web interface can be found [here](http://event.asus.com/2009/networks/dummy_ui/rt-n12/Advanced_BasicFirewall_Content.html).

I had "Enable Web Access from WAN" on and was able to access the web interface via a static IP-address under port 8080.

However, since I was getting `destination host unreachable` when pinging the router (although I could access it via the web-interface), I decided to disable the firewall via the "Enable Firewall" setting that can be seen in the dummy.

After having done this I now can't access the router neither by ping (this time it says `request timed out`) nor via the before-mentioned IP-address on any port I tried (8080, 80, 1, ...).

Why would disabling the firewall remove my access to the router? That doesn't make much sense? (Total newbie here.)
Any ideas what I can do to remedy the situation short of driving 150 km and resetting the router?

Thank you in advance for any tips and tricks.

EDIT:

The router actually displays the following help message for the 'Eable Firewall' function:

> Enable Firewall? If you disable the firewall function, we will disable
>   related function below. Ex.disable Web Access from WAN.

Does that mean I'm out of luck regaining access? :(

Comment: Is your computer plugged into the LAN or WAN port? you should only be able to access the routers configuration pages from the LAN ports. That is what they mean by "web access".

Comment: I'm trying to access the router from the WAN port. It has a static IP and I've been connecting to it for the last few months - until I disabled the firewall yesterday. But yeah, so far it seems I'll need to drive there, connect from LAN and reenable the WAN access.